# How to get the union of 2 fields values from 2 tables in one field?

Tags: mysql, left-join, union

Am looking for the help of some sql query experts.

Having some hard time for me to fix the issue in below sql statement. This is a join sql statement of 3 tables. and i need similar kind of data from people and alumni table. And the field name also same in both table. So my question is- is there any for me to get the similar data in a single field?

```
SELECT DISTINCT P.people_id, P.Name,P.Journal_name,  N.People_id, N.Name, N.Journal_name
FROM  `Paper_Author` AS A
LEFT JOIN  `People` AS P ON ( A.Author_id = P.people_id ) 
LEFT JOIN  `Alumni` AS N ON ( A.Author_id = N.People_id ) 
WHERE A.Paper_id =2067
ORDER BY A.Author_sortorder
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Eg of Current Result is:

```
   Id--  Name--  Journal_name-- ID2-- Name--  Journal_name 
    1   Name1      A1          NULL   NULL           NULL
    2   Name2      B1            5    Name10         NULL
    3   Name3      C1            3    Name3          C1
```

Expected Result :

```
   Id--  Name--  Journal_name--  
    1    Name1      A1          
    2    Name2      B1          
    3    Name3      C1                
    5    Name10    NULL
```

I want to know whether i can get similar values in single filed? eg:both Journal_name in single field?

Comment: what's with the row full of NULL's ?

Comment: better try a union here

Comment: @madalinivascu empty record. table1 & table2 are exactly similar tables. Most of the time i can found a particular person in either t1 or t2. but in few cases  can found in both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) should work for this task. With a UNION statement you'll get both results in a single result set:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT P.people_id, P.Name, P.Journal_name, AP.Author_sortorder
FROM `Paper_Author` AS AP
LEFT JOIN  `People` AS P ON ( A.Author_id = P.people_id )  
WHERE AP.Paper_id = 2067
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT N.People_id, N.Name, N.Journal_name, AN.Author_sortorder
FROM `Paper_Author` AS AN
LEFT JOIN `Alumni` AS N ON ( A.Author_id = N.People_id ) 
WHERE AN.Paper_id = 2067
ORDER BY Author_sortorder
```